# How to get back to our app from other 3rd party app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I'm working on a flutter project where customer will see all invoice and customer can make payment using any UPI app. My problem is how can I redirect with the response back to my app after making payment in UPI app? Currently I'm using url_launcher to launch UPI app but I don't know how to get back to my app with response.

Comment: By using url_launcher it's hard to get correct response after making an upi payment (url_launcher always return true even if the transaction is not started because of an error). 
Instead of url_launcher you can use other packages like 1. upi_india, 2. upi_pay. These packages are able to return the response after making an upi payment.